# There was an error with communicating with your device in Xcode

Tags: ios, swift, iphone, xcode, xcode8

I searched all resources last day and didn't get a successful result. Please take it into consideration that I could test with this device a few days ago. But today I didn't do. Also I tested this iPhone with another mac, the result is the same. The device is an iPhone 6s.
I did the following things:
-restart Xcode
-restart mac
-restart device
-clean& build project

Please help me for solving this problem.

[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tQS5r.png): [image: You can see error's picture from here]

Comment: Do you have 2 different versions of Xcode installed in your machine ?

Comment: When I faced a similar issue the cause was that I had a screen lock which Apple requires to disable that in case you need to run and test an app.

In any case please tell us if you already did the basic steps.

Comment: Seems like other people are having the same issue, which version of xcode do you have?

Comment: delete derived data from Xcode -> empty your trash -> press shift+command+alt+k -> close your Xcode -> Change project directory -> Restart -> Now open your project

Comment: @AlenAlexander no just one version.

Comment: @paokg4 no effect.If I find solution,I'll add here answer:)

Comment: @TNguyen xcode version is 8

Comment: @Gagan_iOS do you have experience with this error ??Same project run on another iphone succesfully. Only this phone create problem

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Problem was due to device OS version.I just updated device version to 11.0 and restared device.Then problem solved.Hope this comment will help to someone

Answer (score 8):

I had the same problem and I restarted my iPhone. Now it's working.

Comment: For those who didn't update the OS and are using an iPad, just restarted the device and it was back to normal.

Answer (score 1):

For others also dealing with this problem and couldn't find anything that worked for them. **I fixed it by restarting my MacBookPro.**

~~ *What I tried* ~~ 
Restarting the iPhone did not help, tried it 3 times. 
Uninstalling and reinstalling the app did not help. 
Changing the Wi-Fi did not help. 
Restarting Xcode did not help. 
Unplugging and replugging the iPhone did not help. 
Disabling "Connect over network" in Xcode did not help.

~~ *What I checked* ~~ 
Xcode is the newest version. 
iOS is the newest version 
I couldn't try another Mac cause I only have one. 
I also only have one cable. 
I only have one version of Xcode installed.

Answer (score 0):

Please check the following notes:

1. Make sure to answer the trust this Mac when you attached the device; If the device is not trusted, it effectively shuts down communications between the two devices.
2. Try any different cable.
3. Check if you have 2 different versions of Xcode installed in your machine.

Comment: Yes,i tested with another mac,another usb.No just one version.Xcode automatically detect device.Thank you for answer anyway

Answer (score 0):

Apparently, this error can occur because of multiple issues.  In my case, when I restarted the iPhone, it asked me to re-enter password for my apple id.  Once the password was verified, I was able to run the application on the iPhone.

Answer (score 0):

Error happened to me because my iPad was full on disk space. I was unaware of this until I restarted it.

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue happen to my iPad 3 on iOS 9.3.5 I just needed to reboot the iPad and allow it to show me an "activation lock" screen (for some reason) that I simply had to reenter my iCloud password into. Also, it showed me the "storage almost full" message on reboot